# Laravel 4.2 Request::get() is empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have uploaded my Laravel to Ubuntu Apache2 Server. I have same laravel instance on my local with Xampp working fine.

I am getting url parameters like this Request::get('myparameter');

For some reasons this Request::get() is not working... i cannot replace this with request->all() or any other because same code is in too many files.

I have Laravel 4.2.22 Ubuntu 18.04 PHP 5.6 with Apache2.

I already did composer update and composer install.

I have a doubt that i am missing Illuminate/http/Request but i am not sure can anyone help me here.

In Laravel logs nothing helpful.

Composer update 
Composer install
Composer dump-autoload

```
Request::get('myparameter');


var_dump($_GET); and var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

output
    array (size=1) 'url' => string 'tracking' (length=8)

Comment: can you add a dd(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::all()); before this anywhere in the code where this happens and post here what you got?

Comment: What is it returning? `null`, or does it throw an error? Does the `myparameter` show up in `$request->all()` when you try that? Are you sure it's a GET parameter and not a POST? What does `print_r($_GET)` show?

Comment: /mypath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:513: @Indra

Comment: @ceejayoz Array ( [url] => mypageurl)

Comment: I have setup a new server so is there any extension i am missing to get my parameters ?

Comment: You could try doing `var_dump($_GET);` and `var_dump($_REQUEST);` so you can see if PHP is receiving the request. If the data is not there is not a Laravel issue and I would bet is something to do with Apache.

Comment: please add all there answers you post here to the question by editing the question. I think you're not receiving the parameter. When you look in inspect element in your browser on that request what is the request url in the headers tab? edit: check the Apache access log too

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `request()` helper function

```
request()->get('myparameter');
```